# Integrating $\oint_ {\partial D(3i,5)} \frac{z}{1-e^z}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to compute $\oint_ {\partial D(3i,5)} \frac{z}{1-e^z}dz$. I think the key to solving this is by using the Cauchy Integral formula but I'm having trouble expressing the integrand in the correct form i.e. $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ for some n (singularity at z=0). I noted that I could re-express the denominator as $(-z) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{(k+1)!}$ but I don't know if this leads to anywhere...

Any help or comments would be greatly appreciated. (We haven't covered the residue theorem yet so I'd prefer to do it with the Cauchy formula or something more basic)

Comment: Are you expected to only do this with Cauchy derivative formulas?

Comment: Yes, that's the only formula we've learned so far that's applicable

Comment: They surely won't work though, since, unless I'm currently losing the plot, $z/1-e^z$ is not analytic at $2\pi i$ and $0$, which are both in the disc centred at $3i$ with radius $5$...

Comment: Isn't the singularity at $z=0$ removable?

Comment: @zugzug I suppose, but the singularity at $z=2\pi i$ will pose challenges to basic Cauchy formulae. To the best of my knowledge, this means either Meow must somehow integrate this "from first principles" i.e. Riemannian summation (or deriving the Residue theorem theirselves :)), or use a version of the residue theorem

Comment: Is it not possible to use the Cauchy-Goursat theorem (a corollary, to be exact) to separate this into integrals around the singularities? That's how I used to do it for simpler expressions before.

Comment: Also, if we have a continuous function that is holomorphic on a region, except for one single point, then I believe it is supposed to be holomorphic on the entire region?

Comment: @Meow What about e.g. $1/z$? This is holomorphic everywhere save for a single point but it certainly is not holomorphic at $0$. As for using the Cauchy-Goursat theorem, I’m not sure which you mean (to me, Goursat’s theorem is the one about the integral around a triangle is $0$) but it sounds like you might be close to coming up with a basic idea of the residue theorem, if you’ve successfully applied this before

Comment: @Fshrike Say f is holomorphic on a region and  we have a simple closed curve A and a bunch of other simple closed curves $A_k$ s which is contained in the interior of A. Then the corollary version of the Cauchy-Goursat theorem says the closed integral of f around A is equal to $\sum_{k}$ closed integrals of f around $A_k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather from the discussion that one can use
$$f(a)={1\over 2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z-a|=r}{f(z)\over z-a}\,dz$$
where $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $|z|\le a+\delta.$
We have
$${z\over e^z-1}={z(z-2\pi i)\over e^z-1}{1\over z-2\pi i }$$
The function $f(z)={z(z-2\pi i)\over e^z-1}$ extends to a holomorphic mapping on $|z-3 i|\le 6$ as
$$\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)=-2\pi i,\quad \lim_{z\to 2\pi i}f(z)=2\pi i$$
Therefore
$$\int\limits_{|z-3i|=5}{z\over e^z-1}\,dz = \int\limits_{|z-3i|=5}{f(z)\over z-2\pi i}\,dz=2\pi i f(2\pi i)=-4\pi ^2$$